# Optional chaining ("?.") javascript operator in Visual Studio 2022, and browser concerns

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, browser, null, ecmascript-5

I would like to use the optional chaining `?.` operator in javascript because it's very convenient to avoid nesting of `if` conditions for nested objects or DOM elements, but as it's a recent feature Visual Studio complains about it.

[image]

How to make VS2022 accept it in .js files ?

Also I am worried about the support of this operator in browsers (I am targetting support for Edge / Safari / Chrome / Firefox, not IE or old browsers). Do you think it's a reasonable idea to use it in regular JS code or will I encounter troubles ?

Thank you

Comment: Which js version do you have selected in vs code?

Comment: Hello, it's not VS Code, it's Visual Studio. 
In project settings I attempted Ecmascript 5 and 6 which I believe should support this feature, but I am not sure at all about this so any advice about how to set up this in VS and ensure support is welcome.

Comment: Having same problem for a while now. It makes VS misinterpret all the code below it. I upgraded to VS 17.1 and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the compatibility table :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Unfortunately the feature seems to be much more recent in Javascript than I was hoping so I will probably not use it anymore in my project, even if it works perfectly with Firefox.

But I am still interested about the way to configure Visual Studio to support it.